# Grouping points in time by proximity using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, grouping

> I have a set of points in time (datetime objects) and I would like to
>   group them by proximity.

These points represent **employee schedulling**, with typically 4 of them representing a single day of work: **arrival, leave and return of rest interval, departure**.
This is not the case 100% of the time, since there may be a lack of 1 or 2 records for a day.

The case below represents a night shift (goes through midnight).
The real database base is much larger.

**Is there an efficient way to do this in Python?**

```
2019-08-05 22:00:00
2019-08-06 01:40:00
2019-08-06 02:40:00
2019-08-06 06:30:00
2019-08-06 22:00:00
2019-08-07 02:25:00
2019-08-07 03:25:00
2019-08-07 06:21:00
2019-08-07 19:00:00
2019-08-08 02:55:00
2019-08-08 03:55:00
2019-08-08 05:50:00
2019-08-08 22:00:00
2019-08-09 01:43:00
2019-08-09 02:43:00
2019-08-09 06:20:00
2019-08-09 22:00:00
2019-08-10 01:40:00
2019-08-10 02:40:00
2019-08-10 06:20:00
2019-08-10 22:00:00
2019-08-11 01:38:00
2019-08-11 02:38:00
2019-08-11 06:20:00
2019-08-12 22:00:00
2019-08-13 01:40:00
2019-08-13 02:40:00
2019-08-13 06:20:00
2019-08-13 22:00:00
2019-08-14 01:32:00
2019-08-14 02:48:00
2019-08-14 06:20:00
```

Comment: You have to define `proximity`.

Comment: @rafaelc This is not true. K-means clustering should do the trick

Comment: True, but k-means is naive. Since this looks like a real application, OP has to define at least the constraints. E.g. `2019-08-05 23:00:00` is close to `2019-06-06 00:00:00` ? are we restricted to per-day-analysis?

Comment: @rafaelc in theory, an employee can't initiate another shift before 11 hours of leaving the previous shift, and total work time for a shift can't surpass 8 hours. Does this help?

Comment: Fair, but I also think based on the information given it's safe to assume we are looking for four periodic points that are not restricted to per-day-analysis

Comment: @fendall I will look at that. Feel free to point me in some direction, if you can! Thank you

Comment: @fendall and you are right, they are not restricted to per-day-analysis

Comment: @Lucas https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Comment: Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: It appears you are looking for a small quantity of points within your proximity parameters.  Simple `datetime` manipulation should solve this, no?

Answer (score 2):

You could define a proximity threshold (using `datetime.timedelta`) manually and check it for each date pair (resulting in a matrix).

Maybe like this:

```
import datetime

datetime_list = [
    ...
]
t = datetime.timedelta(seconds=120)

# matrix that shows if each datetime pair is close or not
m = [
    [abs(d1 - d2) < t
     for d2 in datetime_list]
    for d1 in datetime_list]
```

This might not be very efficient for a big data amount, but it might point you in a valid direction to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import math
import time

def time_to_polar(hours, minutes):
    angle = math.pi * 2 * (hours * 60 + minutes) / (24 * 60)
    return [math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle)]  

def polar_to_time_string(x, y):
    minutes = math.atan2(x,y) / (math.pi * 2) * (24 * 60)
    hours = int(minutes / 60)
    minutes = int(minutes % 60)
    return "{:02d}".format(hours) + ":" + "{:02d}".format(minutes) + ":00"


data = ["2019-08-05 22:00:00",\
        "2019-08-06 01:40:00",\
        "2019-08-06 02:40:00",\
        "2019-08-06 06:30:00",\
        "2019-08-06 22:00:00",\
        "2019-08-07 02:25:00",\
        "2019-08-07 03:25:00",\
        "2019-08-07 06:21:00",\
        "2019-08-07 19:00:00",\
        "2019-08-08 02:55:00",\
        "2019-08-08 03:55:00",\
        "2019-08-08 05:50:00",\
        "2019-08-08 22:00:00",\
        "2019-08-09 01:43:00",\
        "2019-08-09 02:43:00",\
        "2019-08-09 06:20:00",\
        "2019-08-09 22:00:00",\
        "2019-08-10 01:40:00",\
        "2019-08-10 02:40:00",\
        "2019-08-10 06:20:00",\
        "2019-08-10 22:00:00",\
        "2019-08-11 01:38:00",\
        "2019-08-11 02:38:00",\
        "2019-08-11 06:20:00",\
        "2019-08-12 22:00:00",\
        "2019-08-13 01:40:00",\
        "2019-08-13 02:40:00",\
        "2019-08-13 06:20:00",\
        "2019-08-13 22:00:00",\
        "2019-08-14 01:32:00",\
        "2019-08-14 02:48:00",\
        "2019-08-14 06:20:00"]


data = [time.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for t in data]
data = [time_to_polar(t.tm_hour, t.tm_min) for t in data]
data = np.array(data)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state=0).fit(data)
for point in kmeans.cluster_centers_.tolist():
    print(polar_to_time_string(point[0], point[1]))
```

**Output**

```
08:00:00
00:42:00
03:34:00
11:00:00
```

**Implementation Detail**

The reason I convert to polar coordinates for the time (basically clock position) is to be able to describe time as a periodic function, and therefore K-means can be applied and not fail on the boundary of 23:59:00 and 00:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function to check if there a double occurrences in a dataset I think this code could be adapted for your purpose as it uses date indexing.

```
def doublecheck(avail_path):
# Open the file
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    # Checks if the time section of each line are the same as the time section of the previous, thereby
    # picking up time overlaps/inconsistencies.
    for idx, line in enumerate(data):
        if idx > 2:
            prev_idx = idx - 1
            if data[idx][8:14] == data[prev_idx][8:14]:
                print("WARNING there is a duplicate or a time jump for: {}".format(data[idx]))
    print("Finished duplicate check.")
```

In your case, the index range could be adapted based on what you are looking for, as far as I understand your question.

Let me know if this helps,
Cheers!